# How can you find the max rectangular area in histogram recursively?

Tags: java, recursion, histogram

I need to come up with a recursive solution for the "Maximum rectangular area in a histogram" problem. For those not familiar with it, here´s an explanation:

A histogram is a display of statistical information that uses rectangles to show the frequency of data items. These rectangles are usually vertical.

In the histogram, all the bars are usually different sizes. In the problem, you have to find the maximum rectangular area in the histogram. For example, if the sizes are [4,1,4,5,6] the maximum area is 12 because we take the last 3 bars [4,5,6], take the shortest bar [4], and apply the rectangular area formula (4x3=12).

The only requirements are:

-It has to be done in java.

-Stacks can´t be used.

-It has to be recursive.

In case it helps, i have a non-recursive solution:

```
public static int MaxHistograma(int[] histograma) {
        if (histograma.length == 1) {
            return histograma[0];
        }
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < histograma.length - 1; i++) {
            int min = histograma[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < histograma.length; j++) {
                min = Math.min(min, histograma[j]);
                res = Math.max(histograma[j], Math.max(res, min * (j - i + 1)));
                res = Math.max(res, histograma[i]);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Given that you have weird constraints such as "It has to be recursive", I suppose this is homework? If so, what are you hoping for us to do? If you want us to write the entire solution (no), what do you expect to gain from that? If you don't want the full solution, what specifically *do* you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you start with the base case of a histogram with 1 column then the largest area is simply equal to height of the column.

When you add a include the 2nd column, the area may be either be

**1)** Equal to the max area from the previous histogram

**2)** Equal to the height of this 2nd column

**3)** Equal to the area of the new rectangle which has been formed horizontally

[image]

When you look at the third column, it's the same. It's either the max area from the previous histogram (2 cols), the height of the new column (red), or the area of the horizontal rectangle (purple).

[image]

Here is a code skeleton to achieve this

```
private int getLargestArea(int[] histogram)
{
    if (histogram.length > 1)
    {
        int horizontalRectangleArea = 0; //TODO
        int lastColumnHeight = 0; //TODO

        return Math.max(
            Math.max(horizontalRectangleArea, lastColumnHeight),
            getLargestArea(Arrays.copyOf(histogram, histogram.length - 1)) //copy the array, subtracting 1 column
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return histogram[0]; // height of single column
    }
}
```